# How to pass an external parameter to LINQ where clause in CRM

Tags: linq, dynamics-crm-2011

I have a LINQ query which works fine as for stand alone lists but fails for CRM

```
    var lst = new List<bool?>();
lst.Add(null);
lst.Add(true);
lst.Add(false);
bool IsWet = false;
var newlst = from exch_HideVoiceSignature in lst where 
(((exch_HideVoiceSignature!=null && exch_HideVoiceSignature==false 
||    exch_HideVoiceSignature== null) )&& !IsWet) select exch_HideVoiceSignature;
newlst.Dump();

var question = from q in exch_questionSet where ((q.exch_HideVoiceSignature != null 
&& q.exch_HideVoiceSignature.Value == 0 )|| q.exch_HideVoiceSignature == null )
&& !IsWet select q.exch_HideVoiceSignature;
question.FirstOrDefault().Dump();
```

As you can see I can pass the variable IsWet to LINQ query for a standard list fine and get values for first list. But when I execute the same for second list, I get the following error

Invalid 'where' condition. An entity member is invoking an invalid property or method

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just because I had an existing query with lot of other joins etc. and I wanted to pass this additional parameter to it  I ended up using a var statement which dumps the rows to a list and applies the where clause in the same statement

```
bool IsWet =true ;
var question = ...existing query ...
select new {
...existing output ...,
Wet =q.exch_HideVoiceSignature != null &&  
     q.exch_HideVoiceSignature.Value == 119080001,
Voice = q.exch_HideVoiceSignature == null ||
        (q.exch_HideVoiceSignature != null && 
        q.exch_HideVoiceSignature.Value == 119080000)  ,
}
;

var qq = IsWet ? 
         question.ToList().Where(X=> X.Wet ) : 
         question.ToList().Where(X=> X.Voice );

qq.FirstOrDefault().Dump();
```

Comment: You state in your comment to @Aubrey's answer that you need to avoid downloading too many records because of performance but this code will do exactly that - download all records, thus making the purpose of using a where clause pointless. Why not just get the `where` clause to work instead of this second-rate amateur hack?

Comment: Like I already mentioned this was an addon to existing query which has Select clause already. If I want to add Where clause I get error 'Cannot add Where after adding Select'

Answer (score 3):

The CRM LINQ provider won't support the evaluation you attempting. It only supports evaluation of `where` criteria is evaluating an entity field.

That's not a problem. Since you want the LINQ query to only use the where clause if `IsWet` is false (correct me if I'm wrong on that.) So we simply do the evaluation to determine if the `where` clause should be added or not. Then execute your query.

```
   var question = from q in exch_questionSet
                  select q.exch_HideVoiceSignature;

    if (!IsWet)
    {
        question.Where(x => ((x.exch_HideVoiceSignature != null
                       && x.exch_HideVoiceSignature.Value == 0) || x.exch_HideVoiceSignature == null));
    }

    question.FirstOrDefault().Dump();
```

Comment: Remember that this will only work for `And` filters: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18636095/dynamically-construct-linq-in-crm-2011/18637528#18637528

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer. This seems to be pointing in the right direction but the question is can the where clause be added to existing 20 other where conditions that are already there? In other words, this is part of a very complex statement with lot of other joins and where clauses. Can I add the conditional where clause to existing query.

Comment: @SofiaKhwaja - Yes, you can add it to an existing `where` clause. We can only work from the code you provided, not a theoretical query with 20 other conditions (it'll depend on the specifics of how it is setup). As @Daryl correctly points out it only works with `&&` - based on the specific code you provided that is what you want. Now, depending how complex of a `where` clause you are constructing you can work around the `&&` limitation, but it is going to take some work.

Comment: When I am trying this approach I get the error message "The method 'Where' cannot follow the method 'Select' or is not support"

Comment: Step back, if you drop the `IsWet` condition from your original query does it work in CRM? If not, you need to fix that first. I think the issues might be `x.exch_HideVoiceSignature != null`. Change it to `x.exch_HideVoiceSignature.Value != 0` - but I don't think it is necessary. If it is null it simply won't match 0. You can't query for a null Option Set just a null on the Value field of the Option Set - yes, it's different from normal C# where you check for a null Option Set before retrieve the Value field.

Answer (score 2):

I am constantly confronted with that problem.

Try to "detach" (for example call **.ToArray()**) your query (while it is "clear") from CRM and then filter query using external parameter. This should help.

```
var question = 
    (from q in exch_questionSet
    where (
    (q.exch_HideVoiceSignature != null && q.exch_HideVoiceSignature.Value == 0 ) || 
    q.exch_HideVoiceSignature == null )
    select q.exch_HideVoiceSignature
    ).ToArray().Where(q => !IsWet);


question.FirstOrDefault().Dump();
```

### UPDATE

If you are using `IsWet` flag to control blocks of conditions (enable and disable them from the one point in the code) then probably you may be interested in class named [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) which allows you to dynamically construct predicates.

Comment: @Bvrce you're absolutely right - this is the main problem if for example I have only one condition in the where clause and this condition related to the external parameter. In this case I am forced to dump all records from CRM to array and filter them after that. Or simply use loop through external data with calling API for each element.

Comment: Thanks Andrey. Can I also use .where statement by attaching to ToList? Also the issue is that I don't want to download extra rows from the server as the objective is to improve performance by adding the IsWet flag. Thanks a lot for your thoughts.

Comment: ToList is also applicable like any other method that dumps data locally

Comment: A FetchXML query may be better suited as you can embed the IsWet flag directly into a filter condition.